# CakePHP Input form search for product id and show result on the same page

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, input

As the title says it i need to search for data from my database with input form and return the query to the same page.

I have tried many different kinds of solutions from Google and here. None of them have worked with me so far. Also i'm quite new to CakePHP so its obvious i'm missing something..

The table name for my data is "posts".

So the view where i want this search to be is ( search.ctp ) and i have the form there like this:

```
<?php
  echo $this->Form->create('Search');
  echo $this->Form->input('search', array('label' => 'Search with ID'));
  echo $this->Form->end('Search');
?>
```

From what i have found out i'm confused if i'm supposed to use my PostsController.php for the search function or make new Controller as SearchController.php for this, same goes for the model.

At this point i'm trying it with SearchController.php and the code follows:

```
class SearchController extends AppController {


    public function search(){

        $keyword=$this->params->query['keyword']; 

        $cond=array('OR'=>array("Post.id LIKE '%$keyword%'","Post.title LIKE %$keyword%'")  );

        $list = $this->Post->find('all',array('conditions')=>$cond);

    }
}
```

And the part where im trying to show my query results on the page search.ctp code follows:

```
<?php
      foreach($list as $post): ?>

   <tr>
     <td> <?php echo $post ["Search"]["id"]; ?> </td>
     <td>   
         <?php echo $this->Html->link($post["Search"]["title"], array("controller" => "posts", "action" => "search", $post["Search"]["id"])); ?>
    </td>

    <td><?php echo $post["Search"]["created"]; ?></td>
   </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php unset ($post); ?>
```

I bet the code is kinda retarded i have been trying so many different solutions for this so by now the code is completely messed up i quess..

Anyway thank you in advance if someone is kind enough to help man in need!

Answer (score 0):

This is simply wrong, you try to search by a POST (Post.search) but use a query parameter (/posts/index/?keyword=something) from the URL. How do you think should it get there? By the way why are you searching the id as well?

There is no need to create a search controller, I don't get it why people like to do it, but there is definitely no need to do so. You can have a listing of your postings, even paginated, on the same page as the search:

```
public function index() {
    if ($this->request->is('post') && !empty($this->request->data['Post']['search'])) {
        $searchTerm = '%' . $this->request->data['Post']['search'] . '%';
        $this->Paginator->settings['conditions']['OR'] = array(
            'Post.id LIKE' => $searchTerm,
            'Post.title LIKE' => $searchTerm,
        );
    }
    $this->set('posts', $this->Paginate->paginate());
}
```

If you're trying to get the search term in the URL the correct pattern to use here is [the PRG pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). The [CakeDC search plugin](http://github.com/cakedc/search) for CakePHP implements that very well and makes it easy to implement it.

Answer (score -1):

In search action you have to verify the post is sent.
So 
if ($_POST)
{
        $keyword=$this->params->query['keyword'];

```
    $cond=array('OR'=>array("Post.id LIKE '%$keyword%'","Post.title LIKE %$keyword%'")  );

    $list = $this->Post->find('all',array('conditions')=>$cond);
    $this->set("list",$MyData);
```

}